# How to process wordpress ajax call without action parameter?

Tags: ajax

I have following ajax request

JS Code

```
       var obj = {"tree": "suren", "circumference": "50", "location": "penag"};

       var data = {
        action: 'add_tree_post',
        dataObj: obj
       };

       $.post("myurl/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php", data, function(response) {
        alert(response);
       });
```

WordPress/PHP Code

```
 add_action( 'wp_ajax_add_tree_post', 'add_tree_post' );

add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_add_tree_post', 'add_tree_post' );

 function example_ajax_request() {
    //my code
 }
```

this works fine, but the ajax object generated by my client's automated business system can only provide the following format

```
      var obj = {"token": "add_tree_post","tree": "suren", "circumference": "50", "location": "penag"};

    //it cannot add a separate "action" parameter
```

so basically no action parameter, the wordpress function name is added to obj itself with parameter "token". Is there any way to make WordPress ajax call for my function to work with the client's js object format?

Comment: I don't get it, ajax is a user facing technology, why should it have anything to do with any "automated business system"?

Comment: actually the client business system will create a object and send it to another website where the client wants it to be stored. actually there is no click event, its just a post event.

Comment: therefor it is not ajax, you are looking into making an API

Comment: So what approach do you suggest to cater to my situation